# How to correctly position biblatex \autocite?

Tags: spacing, biblatex, citing

I'm using biblatex 1.2a and `\autocite` because I don't know if the final format of the book will require inline or superscript citations.

Seems the correct usage of `\autocite` is preceding it by a space like:

```
my text~\autocite{Einstein1905}
```

This way both `autocite=inline` and `autocite=superscript` position correctly the citation (no experiment done yet with the other `autocite` formats). But I'm tired to enter all these small `~`.

My question:

Is this the correct way to use `\autocite`? Or is this a case to support an enhancement request for biblatex (to automatically generate the space for inline)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! You don't need to include salutation in the end -- your name is displayed in the lower right corner of your post. Also, you can use backticks to format commands to distinguish them from normal text -- I formatted them for you now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the example documents shipped with biblatex, the "correct" usage (or at least the one envisioned by the package author) is

```
Some text \autocite{key}.
```

(See especially document `30-style-numeric`.)

I agree it is arguable that in-text-citations should be prepended by a non-breakable space for numeric styles not using superscripts. (However, non-breakable spaces would often produce bad line breaks for inline author-year-citations.)